# vue.js keditor5 добавить возможность выбирать шрифт

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6

Здраствуйте. Инициализирую editor в файле app.js:

```
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'
import VueCkeditor from 'vue-ckeditor5'

const options = {
  editors: {
    classic: ClassicEditor
  },
  name: 'vue-ckeditor',
}

Vue.use(VueCkeditor.plugin, options)
```

В результате формируется дефолтный editor  для работы с текстом. Вопрос, как при даной настройке добавить возможность выбирать шрифт для текста? Спасибо.

Comment: уточните, у Вас нет доступа к эдитору?

Comment: В даном примере это все что есть, эдитор как отдельный плагин

Comment: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/font.html - там есть куча настроек

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно сформировать СВОЙ build https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
const editorConfig = {
        removePlugins: ["MediaEmbedToolbar"],
        toolbar: [
            'undo', 'redo','|',
            'heading', '|',
            'fontFamily','fontsize', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor', '|',
            'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|',
            'link','alignment', 'outdent', 'indent', '|',
            'bulletedList', 'numberedList','blockQuote',
        ],
        fontFamily: {
            options: [
                'default',
                'Arial, sans-serif',
                'Courier New, Courier, monospace'
            ]
        },
        fontSize: {
            options: [
                10,
                12,
                'default',
                18,
                20,
                24
            ]
        },
        fontColor: {
            colors: [
                {
                    color: 'hsl(0,94%,43%)',
                    label: 'Black'
                },
                {
                    color: 'hsl(0, 0%, 30%)',
                    label: 'Dim grey'
                },
                {
                    color: 'hsl(0, 0%, 60%)',
                    label: 'Grey'
                },
                {
                    color: 'hsl(0, 0%, 90%)',
                    label: 'Light grey'
                },
                {
                    color: 'hsl(0, 0%, 100%)',
                    label: 'White',
                    hasBorder: true
                },
            ],
            columns: 3,
        },
        fontBackgroundColor: {
            colors: [
                {
                    color: 'hsl(0, 75%, 60%)',
                    label: 'Red'
                },
                {
                    color: 'hsl(30, 75%, 60%)',
                    label: 'Orange'
                },
                {
                    color: 'hsl(60, 75%, 60%)',
                    label: 'Yellow'
                },
                {
                    color: 'hsl(90, 75%, 60%)',
                    label: 'Light green'
                },
                {
                    color: 'hsl(120, 75%, 60%)',
                    label: 'Green'
                },
            ],
            columns: 3,
        },
    }
```

Меняй что хочешь!)))